# unable to find my custom node on node-red

Tags: node.js, npm, node-red

I am new to node-red. I have created my custom node and published on "npm registry". I can able to install it using npm command but i am not able to find in "Node-red". please help how to enable it on node-red manage pallet.

Answer (score 1):

Assuming you have tagged with the right keywords (node-red) on npm then it will be picked up by the batch job at some point and be included on http://flows.nodered.org

Once the node shows up here it will be included in the manifest file that Node-RED uses for the "Manage Pallet" function.

Details on the naming convention for Node-RED nodes and how to tag them so they appear on http://flows.nodered.org can be found [here](https://nodered.org/docs/creating-nodes/packaging)